# How to call injected javascript function from Content scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

> test.js

```
doSomething(){
   console.log('Call the function of embadded js file function');
}
```

I have one **test.js** file that I have injected into the webpage like

```
var scriptDom = document.createElement('script');
const url = chrome.runtime.getURL('test.js');
scriptDom['src'] = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].appendChild(scriptDom);
```

Now I want to call `doSomething()` method from content script is possible to call the injected javascript to call from content script

Comment: No, content scripts run in isolated world. You can add another script element that runs a function exposed by the first one or use DOM messaging via CustomEvent. See [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Answer (score 0):

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/4803607) given by Row W help me to solve the problem

Added event listener in the **test.js** (webpage) file

```
window.addEventListener("event_name", function(e){ 
     console.log('event recived in embadded js file')
});
```

and from content script I trigger the event to

```
 window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('event_name', {
            'detail': {
                'message': 'some data',
            }
}));
```